# Customising org-mode link click behaviour

Tags: org-mode, org-link

My current (default) behaviour when click a `[[link]]` in org-mode is for Emacs to search a matching heading.

However, I wanted to redefine this behaviour to open a file called `link.org`.
That is, for every link I have `[[foo]]`, clicking it would be same as clicking `[[file:./foo.org]]`.  How can I do this?

*Note*: I could write all my links as `[[file:./foo.org]]` but I wanted to leave them as `[[foo]]` for compatibility with external applications.

Answer (score 1):

Retask `C-c C-o` and/or add a modifier to the mouse click, like `M-<click>`. Essentially, instead of handling a normal click event, and following the link, they fire a function that opens the target document.